# When can you trade in Pokemon X and Y?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I am probably going to replay Y soon, but I'm too used to all the starters. Due to that, I plan on trading the starter to my ORAS game as soon as I get it. However, I'm not sure if you can trade your starter using the PSS as soon as you get it.

Can you trade your starter using the PSS as soon as you get it?

Answer (score 1):

You are allowed to trade only when you receive the Pokedex and you own at least 2 Pokemon.
From that moment you can trade whatever Pokemon you have using normal trade or Wondertrade.